# What is the best practice for naming packages for multi module project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the best practice for naming packages multi module project in Android Studio? I created a Project with Application Name as `"HelloWorld"` and Module Name as `"HelloWorld"`.Android Studio new project window automatically adds package name as `com.domainname.helloworld.helloworld`.

Is it good practice to name as `com.domainname.appname.modulename`? If I want to create database package in this application, which one of the following is best

> com.domainname.helloworld.helloworld.database

Or

> com.domainname.helloworld.database

If I create package without module name like `com.domainname.modulename`,is it affect other module pacakges?

Comment: What about `com.domainname.helloworld.mdl_helloworld`? Just prepending `mdl_` (I use Eclipse - I prepend `ACT_` to Activities, `FRG_` to Fragments, `CLS_` to Classes, and so on). So they are visually distinct and grouped.

Comment: mdl_helloworld means? is it good practice to use underscore in java package names?

Comment: Why not? `mdl_` for module (I think "module" is something specific to Android Studio).

Comment: my question is why android studio creates package name like com.domainname.appname.modulename by default? Is it any reason behind this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. In Eclipse, is also like that. I find it useful to give a name like **com.mycompany.myappname.ACT_Main** (for example) - `com` for commercial, `net` for free or so. It makes sense, to me.

Comment: If I create package com.mycompany.myappname.ACT_Main in lib module of the same project in android studio what will happen?

Comment: In this case, myappname is a library inside a project. So I'd better call it **com.mycompany.lib_something.ACT_Main** (note that ACT_Main is my naming convention for a MainActivity, not for a generic class inside a library)

Comment: No I need best practice and want know reason behind android studio creates package name like com.domainname.appname.modulename by default?